# Unable to find dataset error when trying to use BigQuery to get download statistics for PyPI

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pypi

I have found [this](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/the-psf:pypi) question describing how to get download statistics from a PyPI project. However when I click the link I get the following (regardless of browser or computer):

[image]

Anybody know what might be the problem?

Comment: i just tried and it worked for me - meaning i see it (the-psf project ; pypi dataset and tables in it) in BQ UI

Comment: Do you need to have an account - or to be logged in or anything? (I've never used BigQuery before)

Comment: you just need to log in with your gmail - also you can signup up for GCP free trial. but not mandatory if you will be just doing `SELECT`s

Comment: Hmm I am logged in with gmail - still seeing the page as above.

Comment: can you just log into https://bigquery.cloud.google.com and see if you actually can

Comment: I think you need to at least accept the cloud tenrs of service and create a "project" at console.cloud.google.com but yeah no free trial required.

Comment: I eventually got there by signing up to a free account and creating a project. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @CiaranWelsh can you post an answer with the solution and accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that querying for python statistics with BigQuery doesn't work unless you are 1) logged in and 2) have given your billing information. Its [free - for the first terabyte of data](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/05/try-google-bigquery-today-now-with-10gb-of-free-storage) - but you will not be billed.